# Binomial; Independent Distribution

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Please advise on the solution to the following questions below. I understand number one. However, I'm having trouble with **2 and 3.**

[image: Binomial]

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide an attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 2 hints:**

a) We have

$$Z=X_1+X_2+X_3\sim\mathsf{Binom}\left(6,\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

which can be easily seen by expanding the binomial random variables as a sequence of iid Bernoulli random variables.

b) Bayes' Theorem gives

$$\mathsf P(X_1+X_3=2\mid Z\leq 3)=\frac{\mathsf P(X_1+X_3=2)\cdot\mathsf P(Z\leq 3\mid X_1+X_3=2)}{\mathsf P(Z\leq 3)}$$

Since if we **know** that $X_1+X_3=2$ then for $Z\leq 3$ it must be the case that $X_2\leq1$ so we get

$$
\mathsf P(X_1+X_3=2\mid Z\leq 3)=\frac{\mathsf P(X_1+X_3=2)\cdot\mathsf P(X_2\leq 1)}{\mathsf P(Z\leq 3)}$$

c) By linearity of expectation we have

$$\mathsf E(3X_1-2X_2-X_3)=3\mathsf E(X_1)-2\mathsf E(X_2)-\mathsf E(X_3)$$

For independent random variables $\mathsf{Var}\left(\sum \alpha_i X_i\right)=\sum \alpha_i^2\mathsf{Var}(X_i)$ so

$$\mathsf{Var}(3X_1-2X_2-X_3)
=9\mathsf{Var}(X_1)+4\mathsf{Var}(X_2)+\mathsf{Var}(X_3)$$

Combine these by using the fact that $\mathsf E(X^2)=\mathsf{Var}(X)+\mathsf E(X)^2$

**Problem 3 hints:**

a) Since for independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ we have that $\mathsf E(XY)=\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y)$ and since $X\mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}}Y\Rightarrow f(X)\mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}}g(Y)$  we have that

$$
\mathsf E(Z)
=\mathsf E(X^2)\mathsf E(Y)$$

b) Note that it must be the case that any of the following hold

- $Y=3$ and $X=2$
- $Y=2$ and $X=1$
- $Y=1$ and $X=0$

Comment: Multiplication hint for (3a) will be especially helpful, I think. Often overlooked. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of comments to get you started:

(2a) $T = X_! + X_2 + X_3 ~ \mathsf{Binom}(n=6,p=1/2).$
Do you know why that is so?
Then one can use a calculator or software to find that
$P(T \le 3) = 0.65625.$ So what is $k?$

That much should give you a start on (2b).

```
pbinom(3, 6,.5)
[1] 0.65625
```

Comment: I have a solution typed out but I'm not sure if I should post it since OP hasn't shown any attempt. What do you think?

Comment: Maybe give additional clues, but I wouldn't post complete answers.